# answer to equation is NaN

Tags: javascript, html

code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>maximum number:<input type="text" id="number"></p>
<button onclick="button()"> ok </button>
<div id = 'div'>
  <script>
    var rand1, rand2;
    function button(){
      var text1 = document.getElementById("number").value;
      rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
      rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * text1);
      var html = "<input type='text' id='id'> <button onclick=' check() '> check </button>" + Number(rand2) + '+' + Number(rand1);
      document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = html;
      var text1 = document.getElementById('number').value;
      document.write(html)
      return rand1 + rand2;
    }
    function check(){
      var answer = rand1 + rand2;
      document.write('<br>' , answer)
      var text11 = document.getElementById('id').value;
      if(answer === text11) {
        document.write('correct!')
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a program that randomly generates an equation. But when I define `answer` it says that `answer` is Not-A-Number. I have tried with the `isNaN()` function to see if it is really not a number. Then I tried to convert it to an integer by using `parseFloat()` but that didn't work. How can I fix my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `document.getElementById("number").value` returns a string.

Comment: How do I make it return a integer?

Comment: use this line like this, ``var answer = Number(rand1) + Number(rand2); `` or you can use ``parseInt(rand1) + parseInt(rand2)``

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, because stuff like `23 * "2"` is legit in JS and will return 46. But still you should parse it using `parseInt(string, 10);`

Comment: See the linked answer. Also, consider using an `<input type="number">` over `<input type="text">` for this; it'll be clearer to your user that numbers are expected. `.value` will still return a string, but that's addressed in the duplicate answer. As Shomz points out `'2' * '2'` is valid (4), but `'2' * 'A'` is not (`NaN`).

Comment: Nah @RameezRaja that doesn't change anything

Comment: Okay @TimLewis How can I make it return an integer (number)

Comment: You call your `check` function with no arguments, yet it requires two.

Comment: you are passing two arguments to the check(rand1, rand2) on button click which receives undefined values, you have to make both rand1 and rand2 global variables in order to available to check() method.

Comment: It's not a duplicate issue, it's what I described above...

Comment: @red_panda check your code I have edited. It will now work.

Comment: No it still says NaN @RameezRaja

Comment: Are you sure? please copy all of the above code and run it again, it will give you correct result. I have tested with the above edited code. https://prnt.sc/12hnkwr

Comment: Yep I didn't refresh thx!

Comment: Don't forget to give upvote to my answer. By the way welcome!